# Need clarification concerning Action<T>

Tags: c#, delegates, xna

Here is a method used to save data to a file which has stumped me:

```
public void SaveData(string filename, Action<StreamWriter> saveAction)
```

The documentation for the library describes the second parameter as "A delegate action to handle actually writing the data".  I am lost, however, on how to actually create an action for a StreamWriter.  I've done some research and found a lot of stuff like this used as examples for `Action<T>`:

```
Action<string> s = Console.WriteLine;
```

And from that I infer that `<T>` is the parameter type passed and the `Action` is the method which takes this parameter. I am aware that this may be terribly wrong.

Basically all I want to do is use `StreamWriter.WriteLine(string line)`. However, I cannot use

```
Action<StreamWriter> s = StreamWriter.WriteLine;
```

Because that makes no sense, plus it is impossible for me to reference `StreamWriter.WriteLine` anyway.  Right now I'm thinking that there must be a method which takes `StreamWriter` from a class which I am not aware of.  If anyone would care to point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

You may ask why I can't just create my own `StreamWriter` and do it the way I've always done it.  Well, I'm working in XNA on the Zune, so writing to a text file is actually quite difficult with all the levels of protection (all apps are sandboxed), and the libraries I'm using right now promise to make it far more streamlined if I can just figure out how to use `Action<T>` effectively.  Plus, I want to learn and be better equipped to use delegates in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the API is intended to be used like this:

```
SaveData(filename, writer => writer.WriteLine(saveData));
```

The => notation concisely declares an anonymous function.  You could write it in a longer fashion like this:

```
private static void SaveToWriter(StreamWriter writer)
{
    // get saveData somehow
    writer.WriteLine(saveData);
}

// ...

SaveData(filename, SaveToWriter);
```

which might help explicate the type signatures involved.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  Works perfectly.  I've seen the => notation before, but it helps to have it explicitly explained.